# GridPane in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have some questions about grid pane. I have [this Grid Pane](http://rghost.ru/47655299/thumb.png).
How to delete vertical line between first and second columns in the zero row?
How to change colors and size of grid lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gridLines` in `GridPane` are just for development purposes. They are not meant to be used in production. In http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html one can read:

> gridLinesVisible - For debug purposes only: controls whether lines are
>   displayed to show the gridpane's rows and columns.